# How to get precise number of messages in Amazon Simple Queue Service?

Tags: amazon-sqs

Currently, I am investigating the Amazon SQS. I am trying to get the number of messages in the queue.

The way I did is to sum up the number of ApproximateNumberOfMessages and ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible (which I got from Queue Attributes).

However, there are delay of updating on Amazon sqs. For example, I will get 0 message in the queue if I just sent the message to the queue 5 seconds ago. I tried to wait for 1 minutes after sending the message to the queue. But, sometimes, it doesn't work.

So, I am wondering what the best way to capture this information. Thanks.

Comment: Another way to do it might be keep getting all the messages from the queue and sum up the lists size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you did was basically the only way of knowing that. SQS has eventual consistency which means its hard to get the exact real number.

For debugging purposes I suggest logging in the requests of adding to the queue and logging in the requests for pulling out of the queue.

You can also add some kind of a unique ID (or an incrementing ID) to each message so you can track it more easily.

Comment: Is there a reliable way of checking whether the number is 0? I am wanting to empty a queue and then delete it after it is empty (No I can't purge, I have to process the messages too). If I make sure no messages are added to the queue while emptying, then can I be sure that ApproximateNumberOfMessages will never give me 0 when there are messages still left in the queue?

Comment: At this moment, no.